# Does browser send request automatically like chrome

Tags: node.js

I have a node server that uses the following code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(function(req,res){
    console.log(req.url)
})

app.listen(3001)
```

When I run this code and preform a request, the console prints twice '/'(req.url). Why does this happen?
Does the browser send a request automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check network tab in developer tool (f12).

There are high chances that second call is either from extension of something else.
I ran your code and my browser made a single call.

In any case, browser do not send request automatically unless retrying.

What's happening in your case? there is timeout and retried again.
If it is WebAPI, you can use rest clients - postman, advance rest client, etc

Comment: @Srivastava thanks your answer.  does chrome send favicon.ico automatically?

Comment: yes. By convention it will search for favicon.ico unless overridden by html tag for icon - <link rel="shortcut icon" .../>.

But this happens only when you provide initial response. i.e that route should return response first. In your case, you aren't returning anything. you are just making a console.log; nothing of req.send, req.json, so there is no initial response returned to make a call for favicon.

try adding, req.send('initial response') after console.
Chrome will make immediate favicon call.

Comment: @Srivastava thank you very much, the answer give a lot of help~